# in function `yyparse': y.tab.c: undefined reference to `ex'

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I am trying to run an example of a calculator using yacc. But I have this error showing every time I run my gcc command. Here are the commands that I run:

```
bison -d -y calc.y
flex calc.l
gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o calc3
```

I got this error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccYEKrb7.o: in function `yyparse':
y.tab.c:(.text+0x501): undefined reference to `ex'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

here is my lex and yacc files

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "calc3.h"
#include "y.tab.h"
void yyerror(char *);
%}
%%
[a-z] {
yylval.sIndex = *yytext - 'a';
return VARIABLE;
}
0 {
yylval.iValue = atoi(yytext);
return INTEGER;
}
[1-9][0-9]* {
yylval.iValue = atoi(yytext);
return INTEGER;
}
[-()<>=+*/;{}.] {
return *yytext;
}
">=" return GE;
"<=" return LE;
"==" return EQ;
"!=" return NE;
"while" return WHILE;
"if" return IF;
"else" return ELSE;
"print" return PRINT;
[ \t\n]+ ; /* ignore whitespace */
. yyerror("Unknown character");
%%
int yywrap(void) {
return 1;
}
```

calc.y

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "calc3.h"
/* prototypes */
nodeType *opr(int oper, int nops, ...);
nodeType *id(int i);
nodeType *con(int value);
void freeNode(nodeType *p);
int ex(nodeType *p);
int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char *s);
int sym[26]; /* symbol table */
%}
%union {
int iValue; /* integer value */
char sIndex; /* symbol table index */
nodeType *nPtr; /* node pointer */
};
%token <iValue> INTEGER
%token <sIndex> VARIABLE
%token WHILE IF PRINT
%nonassoc IFX
%nonassoc ELSE
%left GE LE EQ NE '>' '<'
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc UMINUS
%type <nPtr> stmt expr stmt_list
%%
program:
function { exit(0); }
;
function:
function stmt { ex($2); freeNode($2); }
| /* NULL */
;
stmt:
';' { $$ = opr(';', 2, NULL, NULL); }
| expr ';' { $$ = $1; }
| PRINT expr ';' { $$ = opr(PRINT, 1, $2); }
| VARIABLE '=' expr ';' { $$ = opr('=', 2, id($1), $3); }
| WHILE '(' expr ')' stmt { $$ = opr(WHILE, 2, $3, $5); }
| IF '(' expr ')' stmt %prec IFX { $$ = opr(IF, 2, $3, $5); }
| IF '(' expr ')' stmt ELSE stmt
{ $$ = opr(IF, 3, $3, $5, $7); }
| '{' stmt_list '}' { $$ = $2; }
;
stmt_list:
stmt { $$ = $1; }
| stmt_list stmt { $$ = opr(';', 2, $1, $2); }
;
expr:
INTEGER { $$ = con($1); }
| VARIABLE { $$ = id($1); }
| '-' expr %prec UMINUS { $$ = opr(UMINUS, 1, $2); }
| expr '+' expr { $$ = opr('+', 2, $1, $3); }
| expr '-' expr { $$ = opr('-', 2, $1, $3); }
| expr '*' expr { $$ = opr('*', 2, $1, $3); }
| expr '/' expr { $$ = opr('/', 2, $1, $3); }
| expr '<' expr { $$ = opr('<', 2, $1, $3); }
| expr '>' expr { $$ = opr('>', 2, $1, $3); }
| expr GE expr { $$ = opr(GE, 2, $1, $3); }
| expr LE expr { $$ = opr(LE, 2, $1, $3); }
| expr NE expr { $$ = opr(NE, 2, $1, $3); }
| expr EQ expr { $$ = opr(EQ, 2, $1, $3); }
| '(' expr ')' { $$ = $2; }
;
%%
#define SIZEOF_NODETYPE ((char *)&p->con - (char *)p)
nodeType *con(int value) {
nodeType *p;
/* allocate node */
if ((p = malloc(sizeof(nodeType))) == NULL)
yyerror("out of memory");
/* copy information */
p->type = typeCon;
p->con.value = value;
return p;
}
nodeType *id(int i) {
nodeType *p;
/* allocate node */
if ((p = malloc(sizeof(nodeType))) == NULL)
yyerror("out of memory");
/* copy information */
p->type = typeId;
p->id.i = i;
return p;
}
nodeType *opr(int oper, int nops, ...) {
va_list ap;
nodeType *p;
int i;
/* allocate node */
if ((p = malloc(sizeof(nodeType))) == NULL)
yyerror("out of memory");
if ((p->opr.op = malloc(nops * sizeof(nodeType))) == NULL)
yyerror("out of memory");
/* copy information */
p->type = typeOpr;
p->opr.oper = oper;
p->opr.nops = nops;
va_start(ap, nops);
for (i = 0; i < nops; i++)
p->opr.op[i] = va_arg(ap, nodeType*);
va_end(ap);
return p;
}
void freeNode(nodeType *p) {
int i;
if (!p) return;
if (p->type == typeOpr) {
for (i = 0; i < p->opr.nops; i++)
freeNode(p->opr.op[i]);
free(p->opr.op);
}
free (p);
}
void yyerror(char *s) {
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", s);
}
int main(void) {
yyparse();
return 0;
}
```

calc3.h

```
typedef enum { typeCon, typeId, typeOpr } nodeEnum;
/* constants */
typedef struct {
int value; /* value of constant */
} conNodeType;
/* identifiers */
typedef struct {
int i; /* subscript to sym array */
} idNodeType;
/* operators */
typedef struct {
int oper; /* operator */
int nops; /* number of operands */
struct nodeTypeTag **op; /* operands */
} oprNodeType;
typedef struct nodeTypeTag {
nodeEnum type; /* type of node */
union {
conNodeType con; /* constants */
idNodeType id; /* identifiers */
oprNodeType opr; /* operators */
};
} nodeType;
extern int sym[26];
```

The definition of `ex` is not in the calc.y file but I can't figure out how to use the `interpreter` file although it contains the definition of function `ex`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "calc3.h"
#include "y.tab.h"
int ex(nodeType *p) {
if (!p) return 0;
switch(p->type) {
case typeCon: return p->con.value;
case typeId: return sym[p->id.i];
case typeOpr:
switch(p->opr.oper) {
case WHILE: while(ex(p->opr.op[0]))
ex(p->opr.op[1]);
return 0;
case IF: if (ex(p->opr.op[0]))
ex(p->opr.op[1]);
else if (p->opr.nops > 2)
ex(p->opr.op[2]);
return 0;
case PRINT: printf("%d\n", ex(p->opr.op[0]));
return 0;
case ';': ex(p->opr.op[0]); return ex(p->opr.op[1]);
case '=': return sym[p->opr.op[0]->id.i] =
ex(p->opr.op[1]);
case UMINUS: return -ex(p->opr.op[0]);
case '+': return ex(p->opr.op[0]) + ex(p->opr.op[1]);
case '-': return ex(p->opr.op[0]) - ex(p->opr.op[1]);
case '*': return ex(p->opr.op[0]) * ex(p->opr.op[1]);
case '/': return ex(p->opr.op[0]) / ex(p->opr.op[1]);
case '<': return ex(p->opr.op[0]) < ex(p->opr.op[1]);
case '>': return ex(p->opr.op[0]) > ex(p->opr.op[1]);
case GE: return ex(p->opr.op[0]) >= ex(p->opr.op[1]);
case LE: return ex(p->opr.op[0]) <= ex(p->opr.op[1]);
case NE: return ex(p->opr.op[0]) != ex(p->opr.op[1]);
case EQ: return ex(p->opr.op[0]) == ex(p->opr.op[1]);
}
}
return 0;
}
```

i have a very little knowledge of lex-yacc. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with lex or yacc. It's about how to organise a C project which contains more than one source file. That knowledge is fundamental for developing in C (or C++). Look in your C textbook for a section on linking, header files, and/or organising projects. Or rephrase this question to focus on your real need (how to ensure that functions from other source files can be used.)

Comment: Also, please indent your code to make it easier to read. (Although you could make a much simpler [mre] without including a full parser.)

Comment: my bad. I will take care of that next time. @rici thank you for the suggestions